# Click Once installer, a custom app launcher and Full Trust

Tags: clickonce, full-trust

Will I be able to download and start another exe-file using my click once deployment? I already have the functionality that downloads and updates my application files, so I would really like for a Click Once installer to just download my existing launcher, create a shortcut for it and then start the launcher and have my current functionality work as before.

I think this is similar to how Google Chrome does it?

Comment: I'm just looking for an answer if this is possible or if I will have to take another route. If you have any pointer on things to look out for send them along sa well! :)

Comment: I had the same idea once I heard that Chrome was doing something similar. BTW, from experience using the auto update and other facilities of ClickOnce can be a big trap and there are many limitations. My advice would be do as you plan and rely on your custom infrastructure and steer clear of anything specific to ClickOnce other than to initiate your installation.

Comment: We have now released our application in a quite large installation of 500+ users using Click-Once to bootstrap the installation of our own "launcher" that checks with our server if all files are up to date. If not the launcher installed by click once manages all downloading itself. It works perfectly and the only thing we use click once for is when the launcher "sees" that it needs to update itself, it then uses an API call to the click once infrastructure to re-run the click once install, thus updating the launcher! It's really good to be able to update every single file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for ClickOnce to deploy multiple exe files.  The only stipulation is that one exe must be designated as the "Entry Point" exe.  The entry point exe must be a .Net executable.

One thing to note about this approach - you don't want your users to ever launch your app directly.  If users launch the application directly and not through the entry point exe, you will lose the nice self-update features ClickOnce provides.

Comment: What I would like to achive is to "replace" a MSI-installer with a Click Once one instead. My application has both a server and a client part today, and the client is started via a "launcher" that checks with the server if the actual runtime files are up to date or needs updating and performs the appropriate action before starting.  This means I would not really be using all the Click Once features for updating the app, but my users will be able to install my app (just the launcher) by clicking on a "link" instead of downloading a MSI.  What do you think of this approach?

Comment: It seems a little backward since the reason most people use ClickOnce is because it makes it simple to push out updates.  However, I suppose this could still work, it just depends on what your msi file is actually doing.  If you just want to have your launcher executable copied to a client machine and executed, you should be fine.  Out of curiosity, why did you write your own "launcher" app?  What does it do that ClickOnce doesn't?

Comment: We have a winforms based application runtime/development platform (some would call it a PAAS) so we need to have our runtime distributed to end users of applications built on our platform, but since we want to support parallell versions of the platform itself and to allow for both "cloud" and "on premise" installs we figured it was best to have maximum control of the whole process. We need to have the launcher (which talks to our server to get the nessessary platform and application files) installed as smoothly as possible, hence my thoughts on using Click Once...